# How to use FindFirst() to enumerate subdirectories?

Tags: delphi

I have just installed Delphi Community Edition and thought as a newbie I was doing well until I hit the `FindFirst()` procedure.

What I have is a directory list:

```
c:\BFUtils\01Utils
          \02Utils
          \03Utils
          \04Utils
```

Then, to try out `FindFirst()` to get the subdirectories of `BFUtils`, I wrote the following code, which I feel is needed to simply count the number of subdirectories:

```pascal
sStartPath := 'c:\BFUtils';

Result := 0;
res := FindFirst(sStartPath, faDirectory, SearchRec);

if res = 0 then begin
  try
    while res = 0 do begin
      if SearchRec.FindData.dwFileAttributes and faDirectory <> 0 then begin
        Name := SearchRec.FindData.cFileName;
        if (Name <> '.') and (Name <> '..') then begin
          inc(Result);
        end;
      end;
      res := FindNext(SearchRec);
    end;
  finally
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
end;
```

This, as it is, compiles and runs, but it only finds the `BFUtils` directory.

Searching the Internet, I feel that the file mask (`sStartPath`) is not correct.  So I have tried:

- `sStartPath + '\'`
- `sStartPath + '\*'`
- `sStartPath + '\*.'`
- `sStartPath + '\*.*`

All these options will compile and link without errors, but when the program runs it displays an error:

> "'.'"  is an Invalid Item.

What else can I try here?

Comment: Your sample code works when you include '\*' or '\*.*' in your sStartPath.  I'm guessing when you extracted your code sample, it no longer matches your actual code.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

In modnern Delphi versions you don't necessarily need to work with [`FindFirst`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindFirst), [`FindNext`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindNext) and [`FindClose`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindClose) directly anymore!

Add the unit [`System.IOUtils`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils) to a uses section in your unit.
There is, among some others, the record [`TDirectory`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory):

> Contains a large number of static utility methods used in directory manipulations.
>
> TDirectory is a record containing only static methods used to perform
> various operations on directories. You should not declare variables of
> type TDirectory, since TDirectory has no instance methods or fields.
> Possible operations that can be completed using TDirectory include:
>
> - Creating, renaming, and deleting directories.
> - Traversing directories (also recursively).
> - Manipulating directory attributes and timestamps.

For finding all subdirectories you can then use one of the overloaded [`GetDirectories`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories) methods:

> Use GetDirectories to obtain a list of subdirectories in a given
> directory. The return value of GetDirectories is a dynamic array of
> strings in which each element stores the name of a subdirectory.
>
> There are three forms of the GetDirectories method:
>
> - The first form only accepts the path of the directory for which subdirectories are enumerated.
> - The second form includes a search pattern used when matching subdirectory names.
> - The third form includes an option specifying whether a recursive mode will be used while enumerating.

So for counting all subdirectories you can simply do the following:

```
function SubDirCount(const Path: string): integer;
begin
  result := Length(TDirectory.GetDirectories(Path));
end;

// somewhere else
ShowMessage(SubDirCount('C:\BFUtils').ToString);
```

And for your original code use this as a FileMask: `sStartPath + '\.*'`

Comment: Note that `TDirectories.GetDirectories()` is just a wrapper for `FindFirst()`/`FindNext()` (see the implementation of `TDirectory.WalkThroughDirectory()`, which `TDirectory.GetDirectories()` calls). And frankly, the overhead of `TDirectory.GetDirectories()` is a bit overkill just to count the subdirs, since `GetDirectories()` has to actually allocate (quite inefficiently!) an array filled with the *full paths* of each subdir.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `FindFirst()` to locate your `c:\BFUtils` folder *itself*.  To enumerate the *contents* of that folder, you need to use a wildcard mask instead:

```pascal
function CountSubDirs(const Path: string): Integer;
var
  sMask: string;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  res: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  sMask := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Path) + '*'; // or '*.*'

  res := FindFirst(sMask, faDirectory, SearchRec);
  if res <> 0 then
  begin
    if res <> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND then
      RaiseLastOSError(res);
  end else
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (SearchRec.FindData.dwFileAttributes and faDirectory) = faDirectory then
        begin
          if (StrComp(SearchRec.FindData.cFileName, '.') <> 0) and
             (StrComp(SearchRec.FindData.cFileName, '..') <> 0) then
          begin
            Inc(Result);
          end;
        end;
        res := FindNext(SearchRec);
      until res <> 0;
      if res <> ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES then
        RaiseLastOSError(res);
    finally
      FindClose(SearchRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
var NumSubDirs: Integer;
NumSubDirs := CountSubDirs('c:\BFUtils');
```

That has always worked fine for me.  If it is not working for you, then something else is wrong with code you have not shown yet, as there is nothing in the code actually shown that can cause the `"'.'" is an Invalid Item` error message you claim.

Comment: he is using `faDirectory` instead of `faAnyFile` in `FindFirst`...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I know that. I had made that change on purpose. `FindFirst()` always searches for normal files, on addition to the specified type(s). Since manual filtering is needed inside the loop anyway, it really doesn't do much to filter in the function call, too. And besides, `TDirectory.GetDirectory()` in DelphiCoder's answer uses `faAnyFile`, too. But whatever. I changed it back.